# Filter a Tablix based on whether a text field = "0"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, reportviewer

I've got a ReportViewer report inside a C# application I'm building in Visual Studio which contains a Tablix control.

I've got a Text field with numerical values in it.  Yeah, I know.  But it is what it is.

My customer would like the Tablix control to hide (not display) all records where a specific field = "0"

I can't seem to get this to work.  It keeps returning a "Data retrieval failed for the subreport XXX...) error.  The error goes away when I remove the filter.

I have the filter set up like this:

```
Expression: [Medical_Emp]
Operator: <>
Value: 0
```

I've also tried it with values of "0" and '0'.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out, I'll post it here in case anyone else comes across the same issue.

I set the filter up like this:

```
Expression: =IIf(Not(Fields!Medical_Emp.Value = "0"), 0, 1)
Type: Integer
Operator: =
Value: 0
```

Worked like a champ.